# Why can't I telnet to a Windows machine?

Tags: linux, unix, windows-server-2008, telnet

Why am I not able to telnet to a Windows server machine? Is it because the telnet server is not running there? A remote desktop connection works though.

Does a telnet server run by default on a Unix machine?

Comment: These days, a `telnet` server _never_ runs by default. Everyone with any sense of security is using SSH.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I believe telnet it is disabled by default - if the service is not installed you can add it  through the add features screen.

Probably depends what unix you mean. I would think modern systems would use ssh instead.

Answer (score 3):

By default, telnet is disabled in Windows 2008. You need to enable it before you can access it.

Answer (score 3):

It's disabled by default. And btw. you shouldn't use telnet anymore. Use SSH or remote Desktop.